# How can I implement a "find in page" in a web view on iOS?

Tags: ios, search, uiwebview, safari, find

I'd like to do a search in the HTML content of a web view, highlight the results and navigate through them, scrolling the view to show the highlighted terms. I know it is possible to implement something similar with javascript and stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString from UIWebView, but is there a more elegant way? Any clues on how Safari does that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you surfed any stuff to move around or getting started?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be some ways to do this easily with jquery plug-ins. See [this example](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html). I have been considering this myself, but haven't implemented it yet. It appears that it may be a little incomplete, but I think it's worth looking at.